# Facebook Chat API

Tags: facebook, facebook-chat

How can I send/receive Facebook Chat messages from my application? its written in .Net, C#.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C you could use [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) (GPL) and the [pidgin-facebookchat](http://code.google.com/p/pidgin-facebookchat/) plugin, which is what the pidgin IM program uses to connect to facebook chat